# C++ thread: how to send message to other long-live thread?

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I have a server listening to some port, and I create several detached threads.

Not only the server it self will run forever, but also the detached threads will run forever.

```
//pseudocode
void t1_func()
{
   for(;;)
   {
     if(notified from server)
         dosomething();
   }
}
thread t1(t1_func);
thread t2(...);
for(;;)
{
  // read from accepted socket
  string msg = socket.read_some(...);
  //notify thread 1 and thread 2;
}
```

Since I am new to multithreading, I don't know how to implement such `nofity` in server, and `check the nofity` in detached threads.

Any helpful tips will be appreciated.

Comment: `std::condition_variable`.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is with [`std::condition_variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable).
`std::condition_variable` will wait until another thread calls either [`notify_one`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/notify_one) or [`notify_all`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/notify_all) on it and only then will it wake up.

Here is your `t1_func` implemented using condition variables:

```
std::condition_variable t1_cond;
void t1_func()
{
    //wait requires a std::unique_lock
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{ mtx };
    while(true)
    {
        t1_cond.wait(lock);
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

The [`wait`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait) method takes a `std::unique_lock` but the lock doesn't have to be shared to notify the thread. When you want to wake up the worker thread from the main thread you would call `notify_one` or `notify_all` like this:

```
t1_cond.notify_one();
```

If you want to have the thread wake up after a certain amount of time you could use [`wait_for`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_for) instead of `wait`.

Comment: After call `notify`, the worker `doSomething()`, can the worker thread still wait for the next notify?

Comment: @ChenZhongPu Yes, every time it calls `wait()` it will wait until it is notified.